# Save generated pdf in folder Django

Tags: django

The code below generate the pdf of an instance and the generated pdf files can be downloaded one by one from the browser.

I want the generated pdfs to automatically save in a folder in my static directory or perhaps a given file path. Can someone kindly help me with that.

```
def gen_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('order/pdf.html',
                            {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename=order_{order.id}.pdf'

    
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,
        stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(
            settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf_generate.css')])
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like that:

return FileResponse(target_file, filename='filename.pdf')

More @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: It is not working. I dont know how it will automatically download the rendered pdf to my specified directory. Thank you